# Electron+Webpack = Module not found: Error: Can't resolve fsevents/fs/etc in chokidar/etc

Tags: webpack, electron

I'm  trying to create an Electron app, but many node-libs causes the `Module not found` error, even for the `electron-main` target.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  target: `electron-main`,
  entry: {main: `./src/main.js`},
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    modules: ['node_modules', path.join(__dirname, 'src')],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, `dist`),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
}
```

**src/main.js**

```
const watcher = require('chokidar').watch('./dist')

watcher.on('change', function() {
  console.log('change', arguments)
})
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "I",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/main.bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chokidar": "^1.7.5",
    "chokidar": "^2.0.4",
    "electron": "^2.0.8",
    "webpack": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

This produces the error during `build`:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fsevents' in '.\node_modules\chokidar\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js
 @ ./node_modules/chokidar/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS: Adding `node: { fsevents: 'empty' }` doesn't help.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: what was the fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### tl;dr

Tell Webpack to ignore that `require` via `IgnorePlugin`:

```js
const { IgnorePlugin } = require('webpack');

const optionalPlugins = [];
if (process.platform !== "darwin") { // don't ignore on OSX
  optionalPlugins.push(new IgnorePlugin({ resourceRegExp: /^fsevents$/ }));
}

module.exports = {
  // other webpack config options here...
  plugins: [
    ...optionalPlugins,
  ],
};
```

### Explanation

The issue comes from [this line in `lib/fsevents-handler.js`](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/blob/3.5.1/lib/fsevents-handler.js#L9):

```js
try {
  fsevents = require('fsevents'); // this module doesn't exists on Linux
} catch (error) {
  if (process.env.CHOKIDAR_PRINT_FSEVENTS_REQUIRE_ERROR) console.error(error);
}
```

My guess is that since it is a `require`, Webpack tries to resolve it, even tho on Linux it doesn't exists. That's why it is in a `try...catch` block, because it will fail when running on Linux and they handle it that way. Sadly Webpack (occasionally?) has problems with this.

If we check how this whole `fsevents-handler.js` module is used in the main [`index.js`](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/blob/3.5.1/index.js) file, we can see that they [check if they can use this module](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/blob/3.5.1/index.js#L324) via `FsEventsHandler.canUse()`, [save it to `opts.useFsEvents`](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/blob/3.5.1/index.js#L325), then every time they want to use that module [they check that option](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/blob/3.5.1/index.js#L383).

The `canUse` function is [implemented this way](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/blob/3.5.1/lib/fsevents-handler.js#L194):

```js
const canUse = () => fsevents && FSEventsWatchers.size < 128;
```

So if we had a module that returned something falsy, then through the `fsevents` variable the whole thing would be disabled (as it should be by default on Linux).

### Solution

After I created the (now alternative) solution described in the chapter below, [vinceau](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/issues/828#issuecomment-854306595) came up with a simpler solution: you can tell Webpack to ignore `require`s based on a regex trough [`IgnorePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/). This way you don't have to mock the module so the `require` in the lib will work (fail) as the authors originally expected it. So just add the plugin:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new IgnorePlugin({ resourceRegExp: /^fsevents$/ }),
  ],
};
```

This will ignore the `require` on every OS, but that shouldn't happen under OSX so it is better to check the platform and only add it optionally:

```js
const optionalPlugins = [];
if (process.platform !== "darwin") { // don't ignore on OSX
  optionalPlugins.push(new IgnorePlugin({ resourceRegExp: /^fsevents$/ }));
}

module.exports = {
  plugins: [ ...optionalPlugins ],
};
```

### Alternative Solution

We can create a mock module that will return a falsy default (also add some comments to explain the situation):

```js
// mock module to prevent Webpack from throwing an error when
// it tries to resolve the `fsevents` module under Linux that
// doesn't have this module.
// see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67829712

module.exports = undefined
```

Lets save this to the project root named `fsevent.js` (you can call/place it however you like), then configure Webpack, so when it tries to resolve `fsevents` it will return this mock module. In Webpack 5 this can be done trough [resolve aliases](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias). We also add a condition so we don't do this on OSX where `fsevents` is available:

```js
const optionalAliases = {};
if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
  optionalAliases['fsevents$'] = path.resolve(__dirname, `fsevents.js`);
}

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...optionalAliases,
    },
  },
};
```